# How many binary words of length n , that consist an even number of zeros?

Tags: combinatorics

How many **binary** words (chars '0' and or '1') of length **n** that consist an even number of zeros are there?
I know that there are $2^n$ options overall, and that for every $n$, there are $\lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\rceil + 1$ options for even zeros. But now what? I got lost! 
Maybe I need to use the pascal triangle?

Comment: Not only is the probability of an even number of zeroes in a random word $1/2$, but the probability of an even number of zeroes in a random word *given all but one character* is $1/2$, since that last character is equally likely to give you an even or odd number of zeroes.  So the answer is half the number of words of length $n$, i.e., $(1/2)\cdot 2^{n}=2^{n-1}$.

Comment: One question:  Is 0001 a four digit number or a 1 digit number?  In other words, if n > 0 can a number have leading 0s?  (If not, then there are *not* 2^n options.)

Comment: @fleablood A binary word implies the idea of strings of symbols and language. In that context, $0001 \neq 1$.

Comment: I figured as much.  But it's the only way the answer wouldn't be 1/2 the total.

Comment: If n is odd every string with an even number of zeros is matched with the string with every digit reversed which will have an odd number of zeros.  So half have even number of zeros. If n is even half of the strings will have an even number of zeros in the first n-1 letters.  half of those will have 1 in the last place and have an even number of zeros.  1/2 of those with an odd number of zeros in the first n-1 letters will have 0 in the last place and will have an even number of zeros.  So 1/2 the possible results will have an even number of 0s.

Answer (score 2):

It should be $\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor + 1$ (try it with $n=2,3$), but you don't need that.  Take any option for the first $n-1$ bits, then the last is determined by the parity.

Comment: Can you explain more? Just a bit more explanation would do. Thank you so much

Comment: If there are an even number of 0's in the first n-1 positions, you need to add a 0 in the last.  If there are an odd number, you need to add a 1.  Either way you get one legal word from each word of length n-1

Comment: The answer should be $2^{n-1}$ but I don't understand why

Comment: That is what you should get from my answer.  There are $2^{n-1}$ words of length $n-1$.  The first sentence just points out you don't have the right answer for the number of even numbers from $0$ through $n$, but you don't need that at all.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't common sense say that there should be an equal number of strings with an even number of zeros as with an odd number of zeros?  Well, not if n is odd I guess.  But in that case shouldn't common sense say there are just as many strings with an even number of zeros as there are with an even number of ones (which would have an odd number of zeros).

But we shouldn't rely on common sense.  But we shouldn't toss it out either.

==== common sense formalized: half the strings have an even number of zeros, and half have an odd number of zeros ===========

Let $a = [a_i]$ be an n digit binary number.  (Each $a_i$ is a 0, 1 digit).

Let $f(a) = [b_0a_1... a_i...]$ where the first digit is changed from a 0 to a 1 or from a 1 to a 0.  The rest of the digits are left the same.

$f$ is clearly a bijection.  $f(a)$ will have either 1 more zero or 1 less zero than $a$.  So if $a$ has an even/odd number of zeros $f(a)$ will have an odd/even number.  So $f$ allows for a 1-1 correspondence between numbers with even number of zeros and numbers with odd number of zeros.

So the number of numbers with even number of zeros is half the total number.

There are $2^{n-1}$ binary strings with an even number of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

Let $a_n$ be the number that you are looking for.

If $n$ is odd, there are as many words with an even number of zeros as many words with an odd number of zeros, because the complementary words of the former are exactly the latter.

If $n$ is even, then you can split the words in half, and if the word has an even number of zeros then both halves have an odd number of zeros or both even, so $a_n=2a_{n/2}^2$.

Comment: The n even case is not correct.  $a_2=2, but a_4=8.$

Comment: The answer should be $2^{n-1}$ but I don't understand why

Comment: @Lisa: because you are free to choose the first $n-1$ characters as you like and in such a way the last character is forced to be $0$ or $1$ depending on the parity of the number of previous zeroes.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks. Fixed, I think.

Comment: Yes, it is now correct, but splitting odd and even is not necessary.  It complicates the issue.  The simple statement that $a_n=2^{n-1}$ covers both cases.